# Составить регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, такая проблема, необходимо написать регулярное выражение, которое выделяло бы все, что находится между словами =begin и =end. Если же случай такой - =begin ... =end ... =end, то вернуть нужно только то что идет до первого =end. Сам я написал вот это - "=begin(.*)=end", но это работает только, когда текст умещается в одной строке.

Comment: А зачем regexp? Поиск позиции первого маркера, поиск от нее позиции второго маркера и выделение подстроки между ними через строковые функции не быстрее ли и проще будет?

Comment: Мысль понял, попробую

Comment: Еще обратите внимание на второй агрумент конструктора `Regex`, а именно - на опцию `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Comment: @Dmitry D выставил опцию RegexOptions.Multiline в Regex.Matches - эффекта нет, к сожалению

Comment: Кто говорил о `RegexOptions.Multiline`? Это совсем другой режим. Нужен именно `RegexOptions.Singleline`. Читайте развернутый ответ ниже.

Comment: Так что, получилось у вас с `RegexOptions.Singleline`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...
var str = "=begin 1 =end 2 =end";
var m = Regex.Match(str, "=begin(.+?)=end", RegexOptions.Singleline);
m.Groups[1].Value      // " 1 "
```

Comment: Ленивые шаблоны [могут быть опасными](https://regex101.com/r/dR8uW2/1) для вашего кода (когда текст после `=begin` огромный, а `=end` отсутствует). Используйте оптимизацию цикла.

Comment: В случае огромных размеров, текст надо загружать построчно. Искать =begin. Обрабатывать все остальные строки, например, записывать их в другой файл. Если =end не будет найден, то просто удалить другой файл.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать однострочный режим.
В этом режиме, в отличие от обычного, символ `'\n'` входит в маску `.`.
Для использования этого режима необходимо при создании/вызове `Regex`, передавать в качестве последнего аргумента конструктора/метода опцию [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример:

```
string s = "=begin буквы \n еще буквы =end";
Regex r1 = new Regex("=begin(.*)=end");
Regex r2 = new Regex("=begin(.*)=end", RegexOptions.Singleline);

Console.WriteLine(r1.IsMatch(s)); // False
Console.WriteLine(r2.IsMatch(s)); // True
```